# how to get the third properties from many to many relationship tables?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have models in python django framework like:

```
class PropertyTaxItem(models.Model):
     property = models.ForeignKey(Property)

class Property(models.Model):
     citizens = models.ManyToManyField(Citizen, null=True, through = 'Ownership',help_text="a property could belong to multiple citizens")

class Ownership(models.Model)：
    as_property=models.ForeignKey(Property,null=True,blank=True, related_name='assets')
    owner_citizen=models.ForeignKey(Citizen,null=True,blank=True, related_name="hs")
    date_started = models.DateField(default=datetime.now())
    date_ended = models.DateField(blank=true)

class Citizen(models.Model):
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, help_text = 'First name')
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, help_text = 'Last name')
```

I want to get tables from PropertyTaxItem:

```
items = PropertyTaxItem.objects.filter(i_status='active').select_related('property').prefetch_related('property__citizens')
```

I can get the citizens by：

```
for i in items:
    citizens=i.property.citizens.all()
```

but how to get the Ownership.date_started, and Ownership.date_ended for each citizen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in Django's [official documentation of queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)

Based on it:
`citizens.objects.get(ownership__date_started)` and so on.